# Problema al guardar imágenes en ambiente de producción

Tags: imagen, genexus, permisos

les cuento, la aplicacion funciona perfecto en mi maquina que es donde yo estoy programando, a la hora de llevar el codigo al cliente tambien funciona todo perfecto pero no guarda las imagenes, Por ejemplo tengo una transaccion aseguradora, la cual tiene id, nombre y logo,en mi equipo guarda el logo de la aseguradora, como así también fotos de vehículos asegurados, pero a la hora de agregar una nueva aseguradora en ambiente de produccion no lo guarda, ni tampoco en las imágenes de los vehículos, genera una instancia mas de aseguradora con el nombre y el id si el campo logo admite null y sino directamente no crea la instancia, Ya probe desinstalando sql server y volviendo a instalar, Probe guardando con new y con BC y sigue igual. Lo que lei un poco por internet que puede ser un problema de la carpeta local temporal en la cual guarda las imagenes genexus en mi maquina y que luego cuando paso a ambiente de produccion obviamente no existe o no la encuentra. Espero alguien me pueda ayudar. Muchas gracias

Comment: comparte algo de codigo

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias a los asesores de Genexus que me ayudaron, ya encontre la solucion. El problema esta en darle a las carpetas "PrivateTempStorage" y "PublicTempStorage" que estan en el codigo generado por genexus los permisos de Windows de lectura y escritura. Adjunto un print de pantalla. Saludos!

[image: Imagen de cambio en los permisos de Windows]